# CakePHP Model Chain Find

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model, authentication, chain

I have an object `$this->user` which is of model `User`. This object is populated by `$this->Auth->user` in my app controller like so:

```
$this->user = ClassRegistry::init('User');
$this->user->set($this->Auth->user);
```

Works like a charm. If I print_r out $this->user in my controller it gives me:

`User Object ( [validate] => Array ( blah blah blah`

A typical object. Now I have a `Group` model which belongs to a `User`, and users have many groups. These variables are properly set in the models. Now I want to find all Groups for this particular user who is logged in. So I tried this:

`$groups = $this->user->Group->find('list', array('fields'=>array('id', 'group_name')))`

The key is that I want to use $this->user to automatically filter the Group query based on the owner_id in $this->user. It makes sense to me that if I've got a specific object representing a user and I do a Group query based on that user ... it should only return the relevant groups.

The problem is that $groups contains **all** of the entries in the Groups table, rather than obviously the ones I only want from the current user. I don't see why I would need to add a `"conditions"=>"user_id"=$this->Auth->user('id')` parameter to the find function because I've already specified what user I'm using via the model chain.

Any ideas why this is not working? The sql statment it runs is simply a SELECT on Groups WHERE 1 = 1 (so not filtering at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the object User really acts more like a class than a object. You can say Cake doesn't fully implement Active Record pattern (I think Cake 3.0 may fix that, not sure). So yes, you still need to set the condition for the find. And you don't have to set($this->Auth->user);

You are probably not very familiar with Cake: in Cake, you hardly ever have to instantiate Model objects at all. They are created for you based on the current controller and model relationships that you specify.

Comment: OK thanks for your answer. I am still learning cake, yes. The only reason I had that variable instantiated is because I wanted to use it in this manner - as that is not possible then you're right - I have no use for it.